# How does Rust respect the Copy trait?

Tags: rust

If you make a struct derive the `Copy` trait then Rust is going to make `y` as a copy of `x` in the code below, as opposed to moving from `x` to `y` otherwise:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo;

let x = Foo;

let y = x;
```

If I were in C++ I'd say that `Copy` somehow makes `Foo` implement the `=` operator in a way that it copies the entire object on the right side.

In Rust, is it simply implemented as a rule in the compiler? When the compiler finds `let y=x` it simply checks if the Copy trait is derived or not and decides if copy or moves?

I'm intersted in Rust internals so I can understand the language better. This information can't be found on tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is directly implemented in the compiler.

It affects any situation that would otherwise move the item, so it also affects passing parameters to functions or matching in a `match` expression – basically any situation that involves pattern matching. In that way, it's not really comparable to implementing the `=` operator in C++.

The definition of the `Copy` trait is [marked as a "lang" item in the source code of the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/aeb473803d1ead96fab51224ba3e366f44883423/src/libcore/marker.rs#L365). The compiler knows that the item marked with `#[lang = "copy"]` is the trait that decides whether a type is moved or copied. The compiler also knows some ruls about types that are implicitly `Copy`, like closures or tuples that only contain items that are `Copy`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dig into how this code is compiled, you could take a look at the MIR representation in the playground. In this slightly simplified version:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let x = Foo;

    let y = x;
}
```

the slightly trimmed MIR output is:

```
    bb0: {
        StorageLive(_1);
        _1 = const Scalar(<ZST>): Foo;

        StorageLive(_2);
        _2 = const Scalar(<ZST>): Foo;

        StorageDead(_2);
        StorageDead(_1);
        return;
    }
```

So in this specific case, the compiler has determined that `Foo` is a Zero Sized Type (ZST) for `x` and `y` (here, `_1` and `_2`), so both are assigned a constant empty value, so there isn't any copying as-such.

To see it in the playground, [click here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a90e7b832ba57d062a13604c6c070775) then select "MIR" from the drop down triple dots button just to the right of the "Run" button. For more in depth information about MIR, take a look at the [rustc dev guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> In Rust, is it simply implemented as a rule in the compiler? When the compiler finds let y=x it simply checks if the Copy trait is derived or not and decides if copy or moves?

At runtime, there is no *semantic* difference (though the applicable optimisations might vary), both move and copy are just a `memcopy`, and in either case the copy can be optimised away.

At compile-time, the compile is indeed aware of the `Copy`/`!Copy` distinction: in the case where `x` would be a `!Copy` type the assignment "consumes" the variable, meaning you can't use it afterwards.

If the item is `Copy` then it doesn't and you can.

That's about it.